# Swoole process is hanging forever

Tags: php, multiprocessing, swoole

I have the simplest Swoole code, which sleeps for a second and prints "Run task" message to the screen.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Util;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MultiprocessingTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testProcess(): void
    {
        $t = new \Swoole\Process(function ($process) {
            sleep(1);
            echo "Run task\n";
        }, false);
        $t->start();
        echo "Start main process!\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is that it hangs forever. But if I remove sleep(1), it runs and exits as expected. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According the Swoole documentation, you should use `co::sleep()` instead of `sleep()`

> Note: The native PHP [`sleep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function should not be used within a coroutine context **without** [coroutine hooks](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-runtime-flags). However, if you have enabled [coroutine hooks](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-runtime-flags) the recommended approach is to then only use the native sleep function. Checkout the [sleep hook](https://openswoole.com/docs/runtime-hooks/swoole-hook-sleep) for more information, this allows you to use native PHP functions inside coroutines.

[Swoole Coroutine System: sleep - Official documentation](https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-coroutine-sleep)